# Install Microsoft R server

Tags: r, installation, microsoft-r

How we can Download & install Microsoft R Server in Ubuntu 14.04 using terminal.The link to Microsoft R documentation is given below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/
and the link to download it is as follows.
https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?PId=1962
Thanks

Comment: Following the links it brings me to [this website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/rserver-install-linux-server). However, the [specs say "Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6.x and 7.x, or CentOS or SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (SLES11)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/rserver-install-supported-platforms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view what platforms are supported by MRS please visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/rserver-install-supported-platforms

Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 are supported platforms from version 9.0.1 on. The link which you provided is for version 8.0.5.

To download version 9.0.1 for Ubuntu, you must sign up for Visual Studio Dev Essentials here: https://www.visualstudio.com/dev-essentials/

After you have registered, please download "Microsoft R Server 9.0.1 for Linux (x64) - (English)" from https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Microsoft%20R

You can follow the install guide for version 9.0.1 here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/rserver-install-linux-server

This is the same link which you provided, and will always be updated with the latest version install guide, older version guides will be broken off into their own pages.